# how to return objects from hashmap

Tags: java, collections, iterator, hashmap

```
Car c1 = new Car();
Car c2 = new Car();

HashMap<String,Car> hm= new HashMap<String, Car>();
hm.put("Ford",c1);
hm.put("Volvo",c2);
```

How do I iterate to get only the values(only name) to be printed?

Out should be:
    c1
    c2

Not the below :
    c1@13efr5t4
    c2@234fvdf4

Comment: How do you expect the output to be `c1` and `c2`?

Comment: It looks like you are printing the default toString of an object that prints the object name followed by @[memory address]

Comment: @cyroxis : yes you are right. I dont know how to write the definition of overriden toString method in order to just get c1 and c2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:** First you have to override the `toString()` method in the `Car` class.

```
public class Car {
    // attribute
    private final String name;

    // Constructor
    public Car(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // Override of toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

If you don't implement a proper `toString`-method the method from `Object` will be used when you invoke `System.out.println(car)`, and that implementation returns the following (which is what you see in your current printing):

```
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

The way you create a new `Car` from the class above is to invoke the following constructor:

```
Car c = new Car("Ford");
```

**Step 2**: iterate using a loop.
When using a `Map` you can choose to iterate over the *keys*, the *values* or the *entries*. All of these three alternatives returns some kind of `Collection`. `Collections` can be iterated using various types of loops.

```
// Standard Java 5+ foreach-loop that prints the values
for (Car c : hm.values()) {
    System.out.println(c);
}

// Loop using an iterator that prints the keys
for (Iterator<Car> itr = hm.keys().iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}

// Or a Java 8 loop
hm.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you instead want the keys of the map ("Ford", "Volvo") you can replace the call to `values()` with a call to `keySet()`. For the entries, invoke the method `entrySet()` which returns a `Map.Entry` object where you can get both the key (via `getKey()` and the value via `getValue()`).

Comment: Hi wassgren, thanks for your explanation on the working of default toString method. However, I am supposed to use an Iterator to fetch the values from the HashMap. Also, when I say 

Car c1 = new Car();

I am not passing any name to the constructor nor do I have any instance method like getName(). Given these conditions, is it even possible to just print c1 and c2? Also, I would appreciate if you could show me how to print c1 and c2 as it is by overriding toString(). Thanks

Comment: @SukhenduRana, I have updated the answer to further illustrate your follow-up questions.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String,Car> hm= new HashMap<String, Car>();
hm.put("Ford",c1);
hm.put("Volvo",c2);
```

In your hash map you are putting objects not string.

When you pare printing your objects as string it is geving you output

```
c1@13efr5t4
c2@234fvdf4
```

If you have want to print suppose car name then use following way or you have to implement `toString()` method in your `Car` which will give you your expected output.

```
for (Car c : hm.values()) {
    System.out.println(c.getCarName());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no return directly you can use like that

```
for (Car c : hm.values()) {
System.out.printf(c);}
```

Comment: Where do you think their output is coming from?